# How to pull values from correlation table applying criteria?

Tags: excel, correlation, vba

I'm currently in need of extracting cell values from a correlation table that fit a certain profile, e.g. "<0.6". This could an easy enough manual task if it weren't for the fact that I'm running correlation coefficients for >4,000 items. The idea for the output would be to create another table with a concatenate column showing the items involved and another column containing the value for the correlation of those items.

I'd imagine that VBA would be the way to go but maybe there's some other faster and simpler way I could be overlooking.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub extract()

Worksheets("Matrix").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim Row As Long

Dim Col As Long


x = 1

y = 1

i = 0

Worksheets("Paste").Cells.ClearContents
Worksheets("Paste").Range("A1") = "X"
Worksheets("Paste").Range("B1") = "Y"
Worksheets("Paste").Range("C1") = "Value"

Worksheets("Matrix").Activate
Row = Worksheets("Matrix").Range("A1",        Worksheets("Matrix").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Col = Worksheets("Matrix").Range("A1",     Worksheets("Matrix").Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count


If Row <> Col Then
MsgBox "ERROR: Matrix is not symmetrical, can't be a correlation matrix"

Exit Sub

End If

For x = 1 To Row

    For y = 1 To Col

        If Cells(y, x) > 1 Then
        Cells(y, x).Copy
        Worksheets("pegar").Range("C2").Offset(RowOffset:=i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("paste").Range("B2").Offset(RowOffset:=i).Value = y
        Worksheets("paste").Range("A2").Offset(RowOffset:=i).Value = x
        i = i + 1

    End If

Next y


Next x

Worksheets("paste").Select
MsgBox "values extracted"

End Sub
```

Comment: Figured it out. This worked for me, FYI, this code pastes values on another sheet. Hope this works for someone else.